# sIFR dynamically changing the color of text onhover of parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sifr

I'm using sIFR to style headings and want to dynamically change the color of text (within the flash movie) onhover of parent element.

How would one do this? Any examples? I have never seen it done.

```
<ul class="tab">
    <li id="tab2">
        <a href="#two">
            <span class="organisation sIFR-replaced" style="">
                <object width="300" height="31" class="sIFR-flash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="sIFR_replacement_5" name="sIFR_replacement_5" data="fla/gothamBook.swf" style="">
                    <param name="flashvars" value="id=sIFR_replacement_5&amp;content=Bureau%2520ICE&amp;width=300&amp;renderheight=31&amp;link=&amp;target=&amp;size=25&amp;css=.sIFR-root%257Bcolor%253A%2523d7d9e3%253Bletter-spacing%253A0.05%253B%257Da%257Btext-decoration%253Anone%253B%257Da%253Alink%257Bcolor%253A%2523d7d9e3%253B%257Da%253Ahover%257Bcolor%253A%2523ffffff%253B%257D&amp;cursor=default&amp;tunewidth=0&amp;tuneheight=0&amp;offsetleft=&amp;offsettop=&amp;fitexactly=false&amp;preventwrap=false&amp;forcesingleline=false&amp;antialiastype=&amp;thickness=&amp;sharpness=&amp;kerning=&amp;gridfittype=pixel&amp;flashfilters=&amp;opacity=100&amp;blendmode=&amp;selectable=true&amp;fixhover=true&amp;events=false&amp;delayrun=false&amp;version=436"/>
                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="transparent"/>
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
                    <param name="quality" value="best"/>
                </object>
                <span class="sIFR-alternate" id="sIFR_replacement_5_alternate">Bureau ICE</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried the following which seems logical... but it doesn't work. It's the span.organisation in the  i'm trying to change!

```
sIFR.replace(gothamBook, {
    wmode: 'transparent',
    selector: 'span.organisation'
    ,css: [
    '.sIFR-root { color: #d7d9e3; background-color:#61648a; letter-spacing:0.05; }'
    ,'a span.organisation { text-decoration: none; }'
    ,'a:link span.organisation { color: #d7d9e3; }'
    ,'a:hover span.organisation { color: #ffffff; }'
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `<li>` instead, so the link ends up in the Flash movie, then use `a:hover` for the colors.

The selectors in the `css` parameter are relative to the replaced element, so `a span.organisation` won't work because you've replaced `span.organisation`.